# How can I get the coordinates of a feature in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

So far I have tried with this code

```
feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()
```

but it doesn't work. The error I get is "Property getCoordinates does not exist on type Geometry". May it have something to do with the fact that I'm using TypeScript?

Comment: *"many say"*? [The documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.Geometry.html) should be your reference point and it clearly doesn't specify the `getCoordinates` method on the `Geometry` object, it's defined on individual subclasses. You didn't even say what kind of feature you were interested in.

Answer (score 23):

Yes it has to do with the fact that I'm using TypeScript. In fact in TypeScript you must proceed like this:

```
let p: ol.geom.Point = <ol.geom.Point>feature.getGeometry();
let c: ol.Coordinate = p.getCoordinates();
```

Basically you first have to carry out a cast from Geometry to Point. Then you get get the coordinates.

#### Edit ol v6.13.0

They do now work with typescript, the feature should be declared as follow

```js
feature: Feature<Point> = new Feature()

feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()
```